# Disnake | Бот перестал отображать и реагировать на слеш команды

Tags: python, бот, discord, disnake

Я перенёс несколько команд в отдельный файл (команды с префиксом), но мои слеш-команды перестали отображаться из других файлов. При этом даже возвращение к предыдущей версии кода или удаление этих команд не решает проблему. Ещё более странно то, что слеш-команды, написанные в основном файле, продолжают работать, но те, что в других файлах, не работают. Раньше у меня не было подобных проблем. Что может быть не так?

Пожалуйста, проигнорируйте импорты в моём коде. Я недавно перенёс команды в другие файлы и забыл подчистить сами импорты. Просто сосредоточьтесь на самой проблеме, о которой я описал выше.

````
import json
import os
import disnake
import datetime
import openai
import config

from disnake.ext import commands, tasks
from disnake.ext.commands import BucketType
from disnake.ui import View, Button
from config import *
from datetime import timezone

import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

from Buttons import *

from levels import levels_system

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix={prefix}, intents=disnake.Intents.all(),
                   test_guilds=[992905419582349362])


def load_extensions():
    bot.load_extension('Commands.FreeCommands')
    bot.load_extension('Commands.PremiumCommands')
    bot.load_extension('Commands.AdminCommands')
    bot.load_extension('Commands.Mods')
    bot.load_extension('Commands.Rules')
    bot.load_extension('Events')
    bot.load_extension('Recruitements')
    bot.load_extension('Addons')
    bot.load_extension('Ratings')
    bot.load_extension('Colors')
    bot.load_extension('Voice')
    bot.load_extension('Bot_Info')
    bot.load_extension('Help')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    await bot.change_presence(activity=disnake.Activity(type=disnake.ActivityType.watching, name="Patreon"))

    load_extensions()

    print(f"Name > {bot.user}\n"
          f"Id > {bot.application_id}\n"
          f"Owner > SemiTail\n"
          f"Owner Id > {bot.owner_id}")


@bot.slash_command()
async def level(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    user_level = levels_system.get_level(user_id)
    user_xp = levels_system.get_xp(user_id)
    xp_to_next_level = levels_system.xp_to_next_level(user_id)
    xp_required_for_next_level = levels_system.xp_required_for_next_level(user_id)

    embed = disnake.Embed(color=0xffffff, title=f"Профиль | {ctx.author.name}")
    embed.description = f""
    embed.add_field(
        name="Уровень",
        value=f"**```{user_level}```**",
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Опыт",
        value=f"**```{user_xp}```**",
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Осталось",
        value=f"**```{user_xp}|{xp_required_for_next_level} [{xp_to_next_level}]```**",
        inline=True
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.display_avatar.url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


bot.run(token)
````